# Render displaying frame 1 of cloth simulation instead of baked result visible in the 3D view

Tags: rendering, animation, cloth-simulation

I have baked a 995 frame cloth simulation but when I go to render a still frame at frame 995 (tried 990) it displays frame 1. How do I render the final frame of the simulation instead?

[image: Before render]
[image: Rendered]

Comment: Make sure the physics modifier is set to be visible in the render (camera icon next to the cloth button in the physics panel)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the cloth modifier is disabled in the render.

Make sure the camera icon is selected in *Properties  > Physics*:

[image]